# Kafka s3 source connector: Failed to instantiate Partitioner class

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I got error **Failed to instantiate Partitioner class** when I try to create s3 source connector. What was done:
Installed `confluent-hub` and `confluentinc/kafka-connect-s3-source`, CLASSHPATH was exported. (1.0.1 is latest version)

```
$ confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-s3-source:1.0.1
$ export CLASSPATH=/connector/share/confluent-hub-components/confluentinc-kafka-connect-s3-source/lib/*
```

Connectors settings are default from documentation (connector.properties)

```
name=s3-source
tasks.max=1
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.source.S3SourceConnector
s3.bucket.name=confluent-kafka-connect-s3-testing
format.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.format.avro.AvroFormat
confluent.license=
confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers=kafka:9092
confluent.topic.replication.factor=1

transforms=AddPrefix
transforms.AddPrefix.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter
transforms.AddPrefix.regex=.*
transforms.AddPrefix.replacement=copy_of_$0
```

Detailed error

```
$ connect-standalone.sh worker.properties connector.properties
[2019-10-16 12:36:02,410] INFO Kafka version: 2.3.0 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:117)
[2019-10-16 12:36:02,411] INFO Kafka commitId: fc1aaa116b661c8a (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:118)
[2019-10-16 12:36:02,412] INFO Kafka startTimeMs: 1571229362410 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:119)
[2019-10-16 12:36:02,675] INFO License for single cluster, single node (io.confluent.license.LicenseManager:417)
[2019-10-16 12:36:02,683] INFO Closing License Store (io.confluent.license.LicenseStore:197)
[2019-10-16 12:36:02,683] INFO Stopping KafkaBasedLog for topic _confluent-command (org.apache.kafka.connect.util.KafkaBasedLog:164)
[2019-10-16 12:36:02,686] INFO [Producer clientId=s3-source-license-manager] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 9223372036854775807 ms. (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer:1153)
[2019-10-16 12:36:02,701] INFO Stopped KafkaBasedLog for topic _confluent-command (org.apache.kafka.connect.util.KafkaBasedLog:190)
[2019-10-16 12:36:02,702] INFO Closed License Store (io.confluent.license.LicenseStore:199)
[2019-10-16 12:36:02,704] ERROR WorkerConnector{id=s3-source} Error while starting connector (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector:119)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to instantiate Partitioner class 
    at io.confluent.connect.s3.source.S3SourceConnectorConfig.getPartitioner(S3SourceConnectorConfig.java:612)
    at io.confluent.connect.s3.source.S3SourceConnector.doStart(S3SourceConnector.java:94)
    at io.confluent.connect.s3.source.S3SourceConnector.start(S3SourceConnector.java:86)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.doStart(WorkerConnector.java:111)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.start(WorkerConnector.java:136)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.transitionTo(WorkerConnector.java:196)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker.startConnector(Worker.java:252)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneHerder.startConnector(StandaloneHerder.java:293)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneHerder.putConnectorConfig(StandaloneHerder.java:209)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:115)
```

I am unfamiliar with Java but now I trying to look into source code inside jars. Any help would be helpful and thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you exporting the `CLASSPATH` ? Does it work if you don't?

Comment: It doesn't work if I don't export the `CLASSPATH`. Just didn't find class that implements S3SourceConnector

Comment: How have you installed the connector? Are you using Confluent Platform?

Comment: I installed the connector by using the Confluent Hub client as I indicated above. I run connect-standalone.sh command inside docker container `confluentinc/cp-kafka`

Comment: Why aren't you using `confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect`?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know about this container and I didn't know what container exactly I should run for this purpose, I haven't seen this info in any documentation and suggested that kafka image will be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your installation is a bit screwy. To run Kafka Connect under Docker you should use a dedicated image such as `confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect`.

To see an example of Kafka Connect deployed with Docker have a look at http://rmoff.dev/bbuzz19_demo-code and accompanying [talk](http://rmoff.dev/bbuzz19_video) and [slides](http://rmoff.dev/bbuzz19-kafka-connect)

Comment: Sorry about this :) I ran s3-sink connector inside kafka image and it worked and I thought that s3-source might too. Thank you!